# Recommendations for migrating Areas and Iterations

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools

What is the recommended configuration for migrating the source Areas\Iterations to the target Areas\Iterations?  I have been able to successfully migrate workitems but I can't seem to figure out the configuration to migrate Areas and Iterations.  This will be same source to target Areas\Iterations migration.

Answer (score 0):

If you are migrating everything then you only need to migrate work items and Area & Iterations are migrated automatically.

Otherwise you can run Area & Iteration on their own using https://nkdagility.github.io/azure-devops-migration-tools/Reference/Processors/TfsAreaAndIterationProcessor.html